# Doctrine 2, взаимосвязанные сущности и первичные ключи

Tags: doctrine2

Я хочу реализовать такую структуру

```
User: id (pk), name, ...
UserRole: user_id(pk), role(pk)
```

При описании UserRole возникает дублирование информации из-за необходимости описать user_id и как связь, и как pk:

```
class UserRole {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="user_id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $userId;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $role;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

До полноценного редактирования пока не дошел, но уже в фикстурах мне необходимо заполнять и $user, и $userId. Как правильно разруливается такая ситуация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="user_id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $userId;
```

Вполне хватит

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="roles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

protected $user;

Доктрин сам создаст поле user_id.

А уже в фикстурах мне можно заполнять только $user